# redirection with .htaccess (removing subfolder from URL and keep them into website)

Tags: .htaccess

I just want to redirect this kind of URL :
mydomain.fr/public/pages/project.php
To this kind of URL
mydomain.fr/project.php

I'm trying this kind of stuff in my .htaccess file

```
Redirect /public/pages/ http://mydomain.fr/
```

OR

```
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

(to remove just the 'public' folder).
Its working so when I click on a link of my website, the URL is redirected to what I want, but it broke the navigation. So I can't access my page (error like : The requested URL was not found on this server.) occured.
My question : How do I remove these subfolder in my URL without removing these subfolder into the server of my website ? I dont know if i'm clear, sorry my english is not perfect.
Thanks !
Have a good day

Comment: One strategy would be to _not_ redirect, but to only internally _rewrite_ those requests. That would leave the structure of the navigation untouched from the client point of view.

Comment: Is what I tried to do with :
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
But when I click a basic <a href> of my website, it go to the nice URL (with the subfolders removed) but i have a "not found URL" error.

Comment: Please add additional details and aspects into the question itself, not into a comment here. There is an "edit" link below it, _use it_ ...

Comment: Reason why you receive a 404 most likely is that you need to take care of _both_ directions, the redirection _and_ the internal rewrite of the redirected request.